Environment for enumerate environment
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\reversemarginpar
\@mparswitchfalse%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\itemans}[1]{{\color{red}\item #1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Sample question 1 \marginpar{\textbf{(8.1;C;K\&SC)}}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Answer 1
                \itemans{Answer 2}
                \item Answer 3
                \item Answer 4
            \end{enumerate}
        \item Sample question 2
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Answer 1
                \item Answer 2
                \item Answer 3
                \item Answer 4
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\newpage
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Sample question 1 \marginpar{\textbf{(8.1;C;K\&SC)}}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Answer 1
                \itemans{Answer 2}
                \item Answer 3
                \item Answer 4
            \end{enumerate}
        \item Sample question 2
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Answer 1
                \item Answer 2
                \item Answer 3
                \item Answer 4
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}

This produces the following:

What am trying to achieve is an environment that has key values, say true or false, such that I can display the margin note correctly right beside the number (essentially always to the left of the number) and to display the answer when needed. For example:
Something like
\begin{specialenumitem}
    \item Item description with margin note. %margin note is applied here. Maybe something like \itemwithnote{note}{item description}
    \begin{specialenum}[answer=b]
    \item Answer 1
    \item Answer 2
    \item Answer 3
    \item Answer 4
    \end{specialenum}
\end{specialenumitem}


Here is a different attempt:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\llap{\footnotesize(8.1;C;K\&SC)~}\textbf{\arabic*}]
    \item Sample question 1 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Answer 1
            \itemans{Answer 2}
            \item Answer 3
            \item Answer 4
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Sample question 2
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Answer 1
            \item Answer 2
            \item Answer 3
            \item Answer 4
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

But this adds the same label to all of the items unfortunately.
This would highlight the answer as option B in red and print "small note" beside the number. This would enabled by saying before \begin{document}, \enableanswersonly, \enablenotesonly or \enablenotesandanswers.
Ideally something like:
\specialitemssetings[notes=True, answers=False]
would be better.
Note I am using twoside due to the header and footer settings I have.

I think the enumext package can be adapted for this specific case. A schematic of how this could be achieved is the following:
% arara: lualatex
% arara: clean: { extensions: [ aux, log] }
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumext,libertinus}
\newlength{\itemwd}
\settowidth{\itemwd}{\bfseries 10.} % max width
\NewDocumentCommand \rating { }{8.5a, KSC}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_azetina_rating_bool
\NewDocumentCommand \showrating { m }
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { true  }
                {
                  \bool_set_true:N \l_azetina_rating_bool
                  \setenumext{show-ans=true,save-sep={ ~ }}
                }
        { false }
                {
                  \bool_set_false:N \l_azetina_rating_bool
                  \setenumext{show-ans=false,save-sep={ ~ }}
                }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \myans { m +m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_azetina_rating_bool
      {
        \item*[(#1)] \textcolor{red}{#2}
      }
      {
        \item*[(#1)] \textcolor{black}{#2}
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \azwrapp { m }
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l_azetina_rating_bool
      {
        \makebox[\dim_eval:n{\marginparwidth}][r]
          {
            \textcolor{red}{\bfseries\footnotesize\rating}
          }
        \hspace{\marginparsep}\textbf{#1}
      }
      {
        \makebox[\dim_eval:n{\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}][l]{ }\textbf{#1}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setenumextmeta[enumext,1]{azetinasty}{label={\arabic*.},labelwidth={\marginparwidth+\marginparsep+\itemwd},list-offset={-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep},}
\setenumext[keyans]{
    label={\Alph*},
    font={\bfseries},
    wrap-ans*={\textcolor{red}{\bfseries##1}},
    mark-ans*={\textcolor{red}{✔}},
    wrap-opt={ },
    }
\begin{document}

\showrating{true}
\begin{enumext}[azetinasty,start=10,wrap-label={\azwrapp{#1}},save-ans=test2024]
  \item sample
    \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      %\item*[(8.5a, KSC)] answer
      \myans{8.5a, KSC}{answer}
      \item sample
      \item sample
    \end{keyans}
  % Renew \rating here
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{9.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item sample
      %\item*[(9.5a, KSC)] answer
      \myans{9.5a, KSC}{answer}
    \end{keyans}
\end{enumext}
\showrating{false}
\RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{10.5a, KSC}
\begin{enumext}[resume*,save-ans=test2024]
  \item sample
    \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      %\item*[(10.5a, KSC)] answer
      \myans{10.5a, KSC}{answer}
      \item sample
      \item sample
    \end{keyans}
  % Renew \rating here
  \RenewDocumentCommand \rating { }{11.5a, KSC}
  \item sample
      \begin{keyans}
      \item sample
      \item sample
      \item sample
      %\item*[(11.5a, KSC)] answer
      \myans{11.5a, KSC}{answer}
    \end{keyans}
\end{enumext}
\printkeyans[start=10]{test2024}
\end{document}


Although I'm not really a fan of coloring everything and I prefer to use tags and a bit of color, just comment \myans and uncomment \item* and the output would be something like this:

